# passing command line arguments by reference to a function

Tags: c

I want to process command line parameters in seperate function but couldnt pass them. What is the right declaration and definition? And any resource about passing parameters, writing function definition/declaration?

I will use `getopt()` function in `cmd_line()` function.

```
...
...
void cmd_line(*int, *char[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    cmd_line(&argc, argv);
    return 0;
}

void cmd_line(int *argc, char *argv[]){
...
...
}
```

Comment: `*int` looks ok to you?

Comment: but im taking address of argc argument. And what about pointer array?im getting lots of warn like  "implicit declaration"

Comment: if i change `*int` still getting errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to find a duplicate, but did not find any in this context. To make it searchable, here is the relevant error:

```
main.c:1:15: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
    1 | void cmd_line(*int, *char[]);
      |               ^
main.c:1:21: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
    1 | void cmd_line(*int, *char[]);
      |
```

The problem is that

```
void cmd_line(*int, *char[]);
```

should be

```
void cmd_line(int*, char*[]);
```

Comment: yeah thanks. when i changed place of *, it worked. but now i have further problems:)